Does $\frac{x_m^p - x_l^p}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k^p}$ Increase with Exponent $p$ in a Normal Distribution?
I'm studying a re-weighting scheme in neural networks and came across the following setup:
Let $ x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n $ be the positive elements from the output of a ReLU activation function applied to a layer in a neural network. These elements are assumed to be drawn from the positive half of a normal distribution centered at zero (mean zero, variance $ \sigma^2 $).
For each positive input $ x_j $, the re-weighted value $ \overline{x}_j $ is defined as:
$
\overline{x}_j = \frac{x_j^p}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k^p}
$
where $ p > 0 $ is a positive integer.
I am interested in the distance between the re-weighted values of two inputs $ x_l $ and $ x_m $ (with $ x_l < x_m $):
$
\Delta(p) = \overline{x}_m - \overline{x}_l = \frac{x_m^p - x_l^p}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k^p}
$
My Question:
Under the assumption that the $ x_k $ are positive elements from a normal distribution centered at zero, does the distance $ \Delta(p) $ increase with increasing $ p $? In other words, is $ \Delta(p) $ an increasing function of $ p $?
What I Have Tried:
I attempted to analyze the derivative of $ \Delta(p) $ with respect to $ p $ to determine whether it is positive. Here's the approach I took:

Compute the derivative:
$
   \frac{d}{dp} \Delta(p) = \frac{d}{dp} \left( \frac{x_m^p - x_l^p}{S(p)} \right ) = \frac{(x_m^p \ln x_m - x_l^p \ln x_l) S(p) - (x_m^p - x_l^p) S'(p)}{[S(p)]^2}
   $
where $ S(p) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k^p $ and $ S'(p) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k^p \ln x_k $.

Analyze the numerator $ N(p) $ of the derivative to determine its sign:
$
   N(p) = [x_m^p \ln x_m - x_l^p \ln x_l] \cdot S(p) - [x_m^p - x_l^p] \cdot S'(p)
   $

Consider that in a normal distribution centered at zero (and taking only positive values), most $ x_k $ are small, and large $ x_k $ values are rare.

Attempt to show that $ N(p) > 0 $, which would imply that $ \frac{d}{dp} \Delta(p) > 0 $


However, I'm unsure about the correctness of my reasoning, especially regarding the behavior of $ N(p) $ and whether it's always positive under these conditions.
Additional Considerations:
I thought about breaking down the analysis into three cases based on the values of $ x_l $ and $ x_m $:

$ x_l < x_m \leq 1 $
$ x_l < 1 < x_m $
$ 1 \leq x_l < x_m $

But I'm still not confident in concluding whether $ \Delta(p) $ increases with $ p $ in all cases.
Request:
Could someone provide a rigorous mathematical proof or counterexample to determine whether $ \Delta(p) $ increases with $ p $ under the given assumptions? A step-by-step explanation or any insights into the behavior of $ \Delta(p) $ in this context would be greatly appreciated.

The assumption that the $x_i$ are drawn from a normal distribution is not relevant to the problem.  It could be relevant if you asked probabilistic questions like "What is the expected value of ..." or "What percentage of the time do we expect to see ...".  The question you ask is not probabilistic.

Let's take the case of $n=3$ to make the notation a little easier to understand.
You have positive $x_1, x_2, x_3$ and you are thinking about the mapping:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{bmatrix}
\mapsto
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{x_1^p}{x_1^p + x_2^p + x_3^p}\\
\frac{x_2^p}{x_1^p + x_2^p + x_3^p}\\
\frac{x_3^p}{x_1^p + x_2^p + x_3^p}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Assume that $x_1 < x_2 < x_3$ for the time being (you can handle cases of equality on your own).  Then as $p \to \infty$ we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{x_1^p}{x_1^p + x_2^p + x_3^p}\\
\frac{x_2^p}{x_1^p + x_2^p + x_3^p}\\
\frac{x_3^p}{x_1^p + x_2^p + x_3^p}
\end{bmatrix}
\to 
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
You can see this just by multiplying the numerator and denominator of each fraction by $\frac{x_3^{-p}}{x_3^{-p}}$.
This should also give you some intuition for why they might have chosen this re-weighting scheme:  it puts the parameters between $0$ and $1$ (convenient for numerical reasons during backprop) and increasing the value of $p$ will more heavily "prioritize" the highest weight while "deprioritizing" the lower weights.
You can see that, in your notation, $\bar{x}_1 - \bar{x}_0$ cannot be increasing since it is always positive and it approaches $0$ as $p \to \infty$.
For a concrete counterexample just take $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 2, x_3 = 3$.  It is easy to show that
$$
\frac{2^{p}-1^{p}}{1^{p}+2^{p}+3^{p}}
$$
is decreasing when $p > 3$.
